# Exit while loop on meeting condition from file read

Tags: java, file

Below is the program in which i am reading file with two columns. i.e. Name and second is vote . I am reading each lines and when entered Name by user meets condition i.e. if name exists in file, it prompts that you have already voted and cant vote again. It does search for record but somehow it doesnt exit till it completes total number of lines in my file.

Also, how do i count total number of votes i.e. from column two. suppose i have two types of entries YES and NO in that column, how do i calculate total number of YEs and No and compare them ?

Thanks for your help in advance

```
package samples;

import homework.EmployeeA;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Votes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File f = new File("E://Employee/votes.txt");

        try {
            Scanner s= new Scanner(f);
                System.out.println("Is motion open for voting?. Press \n1: Yes\n2: No");

            Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
            int choice = scan.nextInt();`enter code here`


    while(s.hasNext())
    {
        String line = s.nextLine();

        String temp[]= line.split(" ");

        EmployeeA e = new EmployeeA("hiren", "yes");

        e.name = temp[0];

        e.vote = temp[1]; 

        ArrayList<EmployeeA> list = new ArrayList<EmployeeA>();

        list.add(e) ;



        for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
        {
            EmployeeA t= list.get(i);




        if (choice==1)
        {   
        System.out.println("Please enter your name to start voting");
        String vname=scan.next();

        if (t.name.equalsIgnoreCase(vname))
        {
System.out.println("opps you have already voted once and you are not eligible to vote again");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Hey greate news");
        }
        }   

if (choice==2)
{

    {
        System.out.println(" Please have patience till Motion is opened for voting");
    }


}   





    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("D://Employee/votes.txt");
    try{
        FileWriter fwriter = new FileWriter(f);
        BufferedWriter bwriter = new BufferedWriter(fwriter);
        bwriter.write(sb.toString());
        bwriter.close();
     }
    catch (IOException e1){
          e1.printStackTrace();
*/


    }

    }

    if (choice==2)
    {

        {
    System.out.println(" Please have patience till Motion is opened for voting");
        }


    }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

}
```

Comment: Please fix formatting if you want help. Also would be useful to see votes.txt and possibly have the code trimmed down to the relevant parts.

Comment: babubhai yes
hiren No
bob Yes
samir Yes
Canon No

Answer (score 0):

To exit reading the file once a name matches an existing entry, use 'break' statement. In java, the break statement is used to exit a for loop (which is what you need in this case) and since the entries in the file are being read from inside the loop, it exits reading the file. So modify this section of code to:

```
    if (t.name.equalsIgnoreCase(vname))
    {
        System.out.println("opps you have already voted once and you are not eligible to vote again");
        break; // This statement will exit the terminate the loop immediately
    }
```

Since there is no code section that you have mentioned for counting the number of votes, I can give you a basic code algorithm which you should be able to easily implement.

```
    String line; // make this string hold each line in the file
    int yes = 0, no = 0; 
    Scanner s = new Scanner(f) // Start reading from the top of the file
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        line = s.nextLine();
        String[] values = line.split(" ");
        String vote = values[1] // Assuming it is name followed by vote
        if (vote.equalsIgnoreCase("No")) // Or you can directly use values[1].equalsIgnoreCase("No")
            yes++;
        else
            no++;
    }
    // Now yes holds count of "Yes" votes and no holds count of "No" votes
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. But the problem is, it start from first line and even after adding break to it, it doesnt come out of loop. As you said (and since the entries in the file are being read from inside the loop, it exits reading the file. So modify this section of code to:) i dint really got this so can you please help me understand it ?

Comment: if user has already voted it would display message as mentioned above and it should exit the loop. If at all user has not voted, entry wil be added to text file and then count the total number of yes and no votes.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question but I'll try to explain - the break statement is used to exit the for loop inside which it is placed. In your case, the for loop starts iterating from the start of the file (and this is correct and expected). When a name match is encountered, it basically terminates the for loop - thereby stopping the iteration over the entries in the file and then exiting it. Looking through your code, it looks like you have a logical error - to add the entry (if not present, into the new file) put your FileWriter section into the else block that prints "Hey great news"

Comment: Since the FileWriter section is currently in the for loop block, when a match is encountered, the for loop terminates and this portion of the code never executes.

Comment: Hi Sunil, Thanks verymuch i really appreciate your quick respone on this. I did get the logic exiting through for loop using break; but then for somereason i am not able to get it implemented. What i am doing is(if option==1), i would like to enter name of the user and as soon as i enter name of the user, program should check from the file whether name exists in it or not. what is happening here is, When i enter name; it start search from 1st line and lets say entered name is on 6th position, it wont give me answer till i continue entering same name 6times. hope you got my question now.

Comment: I think I see what the problem is - the for loop is inside a while loop. So even though the for loop exits, the while loop still continues and then restarts the for loop as long as there is a next line in the code. To start with, I'd say take out the while loop and try reading only using the for loop (there is not enough details about the EmployeeA class for me to tell what it's being used for or even if it is necessary). Try using only for loop and that is enough for the output that you want. Then you can implement other functionality.

Comment: Try avoiding using a loop inside another loop when reading from files - it becomes tricky to keep track of the line being read. Use just for loop and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks snil but its not helping me :-). Dont really know what to do . i have taken it out but its not helping . Can you try and post me code ?.

Comment: Hi.. can you try it out this way - complete the while loop before you start with the for loop (this way you read all the data into the list and then start iterating over the objects in the list). I can't paste the code here because the comments have a word limit and formatting code in comments is quite difficult. Also, I'm not sure what the Employee A class is about.

Comment: Hi Sunil, i have manged to come out of loop but now there is another problem for counting total number of yes and no votes from coulun 2 of file. how can  i calculate total yes and total no votes ?.

Comment: I have mentioned the code to calculate the yes and no votes in the answer above. Have you tried it out (and if yes, what happened)? Don't forget that this section of the code has to be outside the for loop since it needs to iterate through the entire file.